# How to designate a column of polygons as a georeference

Tags: carto

I uploaded a dataset with a column of polygons, but the map is blank. It's been a few years since someone has asked this question and looks like the dashboard has changed since then. How do I designate that column of polygons as the georeference for a map?

I read there was a 'georeference' button near the 'export' button on the previous dashboard. The polygons are pandas objects like this:
`POLYGON ((1006076.28338623 262138.1090087891`
Which is the same as I see here in [this map](http://oneclick.cartodb.com/?file=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps-public.geo.nyu.edu%2Fgeoserver%2Fsdr%2Fwfs%2F%3Fservice%3Dwfs%26version%3D2.0.0%26request%3DGetFeature%26srsName%3DEPSG%253A4326%26outputformat%3Dapplication%252Fjson%26typeName%3Dsdr%253Anyu_2451_34562&provider=NYUSpatialDataRepository&logo=https%3A%2F%2Fgeo.nyu.edu%2Fassets%2Freal250-c393c31c117191fd87d686168c6784ecb75159bec4969597b4b0d56e6ddcbc11.png)

Comment: What's the older answer? What is your format of your column of polygons?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on projection, but assuming it is Spherical mercator, then you may try in SQL window following command: `UPDATE <yourtable> SET the_geom_webmercator = ST_GeomFromText(<yourcolumn>)`

Comment: Did it work? If yes, please mark answer as resolved. Thanks!